# Delphi trouble: Sorting a Tobjectlist<>

Tags: delphi, sorting, generics, delphi-2010, tobjectlist

I want to sort my generic tobjectlist using the built-in sort method.

here is what I do:

```
//create the list object
myList := TObjectList<MyType>.Create(false);   

[...] //populate the list with unsorted entries

//sort the list
myList.sort(@Comparer);

[...]//store sorted results back to array

myList.Destroy;
```

my Comparer function looks like this:

```
function Comparer(Item1, Item2 : pointer):integer;
begin
  result := myCompare(item1, item2);
end;
```

According to the specs, it should work like this.

I get an compiler error E2250 *No overloaded version of 'Sort' exist with these parameters* (exact wording differs, i use a non english version of RAD Studio)

I have no idea why this should not be valid Pascal - does anyone of you have insight to share on this?

Comment: Although Leonardo and I offered more detail, Rob's answer is the most useful to you. The compiler generally gives clear reasons why it objects to something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. Since I don't know what `MyType` is you may need to change the call to your `myCompare` function.

```
myList.Sort(TComparer<MyType>.Construct(
   function (const L, R: MyType): integer
   begin
     result := myCompare(L, R);
   end
));
```

Comment: +1 Leonardo. es bueno ver a otro programador delphi chileno por aqui ,pense que estaba solo ;).

Comment: Bueno me referia en realidad a StackOverflow, pero sobre delphi tienes razon, al parecer somos una raza en extinción.

Comment: thanks a lot, it finally works (i was mising the unit generics.defaults in my uses clause)

Comment: In this case, couldn't you simply call `myList.Sort(TComparer<MyType>.Construct(myCompare));`

Comment: @alondono probably, but that's how the OP implemented `Comparer`.

Answer (score 6):

`TObjectList<T>.Sort` is declared as:

```
procedure Sort(const AComparer: IComparer<T>);
```

`IComparer<T>` is defined as:

```
IComparer<T> = interface
  function Compare(const Left, Right: T): Integer;
end;
```

You are instantiating `TObjectList<MyType>` and so you need to pass an `IComparer<MyType>` to `Sort`. In order to do this you will need an object to provide a concrete implementation of that interface.

One obvious way to do this would be to subclass `TObjectList<MyType>` and implement the interface there.

Another way to do this is to use `TComparer<T>` to create an `IComparer<T>` on demand using its `Construct` class function. You would need to supply a comparison function:

```
TComparison<T> = reference to function(const Left, Right: T): Integer;
```

Leonardo's answer demonstrates how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If the compiler says no overloaded version exists with that parameter type, ask yourself what overloads *do* exist. Check the source code or [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Collections.TList.Sort) to find out.

There you'll see that `TObjectList<T>` inherits two `Sort` methods from `TList<T>`. One takes no arguments, and the other takes a reference to something implementing the [`IComparer<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Defaults.IComparer) interface. Your standalone function doesn't fit that. Write a descendant of [`TComparer<MyType>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Defaults.TComparer) and override its `Compare` method.